# Replace string with different strings containing pattern

Tags: php, html, arrays, search

Say you have a string like

```
$str = "<img src='i12'><img src='i105'><img src='i12'><img src='i24'><img src='i15'>....";
```

is it possible to replace every `i+n` by the `n`th value of an array called `$arr`
so that for example `<img src='i12'>` is replaced by `<img src='$arr[12]'>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd simply parse the markup, and process/alter it accordingly:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);//parse your markup string
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');//get all images
$cleanStr = '';//the result string
foreach($imgs as $img)
{
    $img->setAttribute(
        'src',
        //get value of src, chop of first char (i)
        //use that as index, optionally cast to int
        $array[substr($img->getAttribute('src'), 1)]
    );
    $cleanStr .= $dom->saveXML($img);//get string representation of node
}
echo $cleanStr;//echoes new markup
```

## working demo [here](https://eval.in/208659)

Now in the demo, you'll see the src attributes are replaced with a string like `$array[n]`, the code above will replace the values with the value of an array...

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this:

```
$pattern="/(src=)'\w(\d+)'/";
$replacement = '${1}\'\$arr[$2]\'';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

`$pattern="/(src=)'\w(\d+)'/";`

- It matches blocks of text like `src='letter + digits'`.
- This catches the `src=` and digit blocks to be able to print them back.

`$replacement = '${1}\'\$arr[$2]\'';`

- This makes the replacement itself.

#### Test

```
php > $str = "<img src='i12'><img src='i105'><img src='i12'><img src='i24'><img src='i15'>....";
php > $pattern="/(src=)'\w(\d+)'/";
php > $replacement = '${1}\'\$arr[$2]\'';
php > echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
<img src='$arr[12]'><img src='$arr[105]'><img src='$arr[12]'><img src='$arr[24]'><img src='$arr[15]'>....
```